# How to programmatically access, accept and move on with the Browser certificate alert window

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

While accessing one of our internal apps, a browser(chrome) window pops up even before arriving at the login page of the application. This window is not the usual alert box, or windows pop-up or any such usual things which we normally can handle easily using Selenium alert access mechanism. None of those techniques are working. This is a browser alert box-like window(chrome) where in it asks to choose the certificate to authenticate myself to the website running the application.Screenshot attached to the message. Does anyone has come across this issue and solved it ?

Answer (score 0):

To accept the browser ssl certificate, you can use desire capabilities for the driver. Use the following code to set the chrome driver capabilities.

```
DesiredCapabilities handlSSLCertError = DesiredCapabilities.chrome ()       
handlSSLCertError .setCapability (CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true)
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver (handlSSLCertError );
```